# Calendar API is gone and can not be added in Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I developed a Google Calendar Trigger which runs whenever the calendar of a user is changed and does some things...

Recently I had to change something which basically checks the visibility of an event. Something like this:

```
if(event.getVisibility() === GoogleAppsScript.Calendar.Visibility.CONFIDENTIAL){
// do something
}
```

I pushed this to the AppScript Project (using clasp) and received the following error:

```
ReferenceError: GoogleAppsScript is not defined
```

Which is very strange because this namespace is used all around the code...

So I looked in the project and for some reason the Calendar API is not added to the project:
[image]

Even though it is added in the appscript.json like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "AdminDirectory",
        "serviceId": "admin",
        "version": "directory_v1"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "AdminReports",
        "serviceId": "admin",
        "version": "reports_v1"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Calendar",
        "serviceId": "calendar",
        "version": "v3"
      }
    ],
```

Furthermore, there is no Calendar API when I want to add it via the +. (The API is enabled in the gcloud project)

[image]

What is going on??

Comment: Were you able to find the Calendar API in the advanced services as mentioned by [Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n) in his [answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74320510/17926591) Or is it completely missing from the list as stated in your post? `there is no Calendar API when I want to add it via the +`

Comment: Now I think that you missed that the services section has a scroll bar.

Comment: I added a screenshot and scrolled to the position where the CalendarAPI should be (at least when its alphabetically ordered)

Comment: As suggested in a comment in my answer, post a new question including a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

`GoogleAppsScript` is not built-in Class, but CalendarApp is.

Instead of `GoogleAppsScript.Calendar.Visibility.CONFIDENTIAL`
use `CalendarApp.Visibility.CONFIDENTIAL`

---

I think that you might missed that the Services section has a scroll bar. By the other hand, the image doesn't match the appsscript.json as it doesn't include the People API.

---

The Calendar API is available as an Advanced Service
[image]

---

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Comment: thank you,  CalendarApp.Visibility.CONFIDENTIAL does not through an error when compiling.
I removed the people api when I posted the appscript.json because I did not want to clutter it.
However, there is still no CalendarAPI I can select, and I scrolled all the way down

Comment: What do you mean by "when compiling"? Instead of replying here, post a new question including a [mcve]. P.S. If you are using TypeScript you should not mess with code in the Google Apps Script IDE, whatever change that you need to do, it's better to it in the code editor and / or by using CLASP commands.

Comment: thanks, I tried to put this in a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74329157/googleappsscript-is-not-defined-in-google-calendar-trigger-when-using-typescript